# Create Custom Column name in sqlite table in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to create a table in SQLite with Python where the column names will be stored in a variable.

```
import sqlite3 as lite<br>
con = lite.connect('MyData.db')

name = raw_input() # I am taking values from user here
id1 = raw_input()
a=con.execute("CREATE TABLE PROD_SA_U_1(
    name TEXT,
    ids INT")
```

Instead of the column being named as "name","id" , I want what the user inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply substitute the names the user provides in the query string.

Example:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('MyData.db')

field_1 = raw_input()
field_2 = raw_input()

query = "CREATE TABLE PROD_SA_U_1( %s TEXT, %s INT)"

a = con.execute(query % (field_1, field_2))
```

However, note that this approach is vulnurable to running incorrect queries if the fields are not validated, so you should sanitise the fields before passing them further. For example, a malicious user might pass a `Drop database` query within your arguments.

Comment: @SaurabhAdhikary Cool. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your query was resolved :)

Comment: Sure, slight change , for INT we will use %d.

Anyway , Ty for ya help, solved my purpose.

Pls upvote my question too. :)